# VBS regex extract multiple blocks

Tags: regex, vbscript

I want to extract multiple blocks of text using regex. My regex gets the correct start but also returns everything to the end of my file.

I am using:

```
re.ignorecase = true
re.multiline = false
re.global = true
re.pattern = "\balias\s=\sX[\s\S]{1,}end"
```

An example of the file format is:

```
Metadata Begin
    Easting Begin
        alias = X
        projection = "geodetic"
        datum = "GDA94"
    Easting End
    Northing Begin
        alias = Y
        projection = "geodetic"
        datum = "GDA94"
    Northing End
Metadata End
```

I want to extract the text starting at `alias` up to the next `End` for each occurrence so I can deal with the details one alias at a time. e.g.

```
    alias = X
    projection = "geodetic"
    datum = "GDA94"
Easting End
```

But this does not get the first `End` after the `alias`. Instead the `[\s\S]` is matching everything after that first `alias` up to the end of the file. But `[\s\S]` is the only trick I can think of get past the CrLf at the end of each line.

Is there a regex that match upto the first `End` over multiple lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a non-greedy regex. `[\s\S]{1,}` is greedy which matches all the characters as much as possible. To make this pattern to stop once it finds the match match, you need to add a non-greedy quantifier `?` next to `{1,}`. So it would be like `[\s\S]{1,}?`. This could written even in more simpler form as `[\s\S]+?`.

```
re.pattern = "\balias\s=\sX[\s\S]+?end"
```

Add `\b` before and after to the string `end` if necessary.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zF0kW1/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a multi-step approach.

1. Single out the blocks:

   ```vb
   (Easting|Northing) Begin([\s\S]*?)\1 End
   ```
2. Process their contents line by line

   ```
   (\S+)\s+=\s+("?)(.*)\2
   ```

So, when put together, we get

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim reBlock, reLine, input
Dim blockType, blockBody, name, value

Set reBlock = New RegExp
Set reLine = New RegExp

input = LoadYourFile()

reBlock.Pattern = "(Easting|Northing) Begin([\s\S]*?)\1 End"
reBlock.Global = True
reBlock.IgnoreCase = True

reLine.Pattern = "(\S+)\s+=\s+(""?)(.*)\2"
reLine.Global = True
reLine.IgnoreCase = True

For Each block In reBlock.Execute(input)
    blockType = block.SubMatches(0)
    blockBody = block.SubMatches(1)
    For Each line In reLine.Execute(blockBody)
        name = line.SubMatches(0)
        value = line.SubMatches(2)
        WScript.Echo blockType & ": " & name & " = " & value
    Next
Next
```

Notable features

- non-greedy matching, as explained in @AvinashRaj's answer.
- back-references *within* the regular expression
- structured approach allows easy output of context information (i.e. "Which block does this value belong to?")

Comment: Thanks for the extensive example.